# SubView Added to UITableView Below Navigation Bar Incorrect Y Value

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uinavigationbar, subview

I have a UITableViewController that's embedded in a UINavigationController embedded in a UITabBarController.

I am attempting to add a sub view to block out the area between the nav bar and tab bar when a condition isn't met, yet the sub view i add isn't quite in the correct place. It seems to be shifted up about the height of the status bar and nav bar combined (notice the gap below the shaded area...that should be shaded as well).

[image]

Here's how I'm trying to accomplish it:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    setupLinks()
    addBlockViewIfRequired()
  }
  
  override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    blockView.removeFromSuperview()
  }
  override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    setSizeOfBlockView()
  }
  
  func addBlockViewIfRequired() {
    if dataModel.getAccounts().isEmpty {
      if let navController = self.navigationController {
        blockView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        blockView.alpha = 0.5
        setSizeOfBlockView()
        navController.view.insertSubview(blockView, belowSubview: navController.navigationBar)
      }
    }
  }
  
  func setSizeOfBlockView() {
    let blockViewRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height)
    blockView.frame = blockViewRect
  }
```

Any ideas as to what I would need to adjust to make this sub view be correctly placed? Thank you!

Comment: Do not include solution to question please (post a separate answer instead).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing your view is partially under your navigationBar. You can use the UI debugger to double check.

You will need to set the blockViewRect.origin.y to the bottom of your navBar e.g.

```
let blockViewRect = CGRectMake(0, navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.maxY, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height)
```

And just to pretty things up a bit...

```
var blockViewRect = self.view.bounds
blockViewRect.origin.y = navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.maxY
```

FYI, the correct navigationController may be in one of your VC's parentViewControllers.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you trying to put this blockingView into **navigation controller's rootView**?

The navigation controller should be completely oblivious to particular business context details. The fix will be simple but there is some fundamental programming principles behind the problem so think about it.
The requirement is "show a blockView if the account is empty". But with every requirement comes a question -> Who should be responsible for dealing with this requirement? Which entity/object?

Architecting software is basically division of these responsibilities.
The correct responsible entity in your case for showing the blocking View is the viewController that is **in** navigation controller's stack. It's the one that shows the table view if I can assume from the screenshot.

So instead of this

```
navController.view.insertSubview(blockView, belowSubview:navController.navigationBar)
```

I would expect a private convenience method in the respective view controller

```
 setupBlockView() {

     //here you set up your view..everything (color, content, position in view hierachy..whatever) **except** layout (size and position)

    self.view.addSubView(blockView)

}
```

You call this method from `viewDidLoad` instead of `viewDidAppear`. As far as I can assume you have a blockView property which will keep the view alive. Should be private btw.

Next, in `viewWillAppear` you would then use a very simple

```
blockView.hidden = model.account.isEmpty
```

Nice to see somebody using 'layoutSubviews' to lay out subviews :) But once you apply the changes above..you layout becomes very simple..get rid of convenience method and just say directly in layout subviews

```
blockView.frame = self.view.bounds
```

The bounds approach is correct. You want to only copy the size, and not have nonzero position.
Have you notice how **many** lines of code did we get rid of? :)

Comment: This'll work with whichever view controller. And when this view controller moves into a different "bucket" (for example no more navigation bar..etc...)..it will keep working as it ONLY depends on its own view controller. The code suggestions from PEEJWEEJ on the contrary will stop working. His solution only is fixing the symptom, not the cause.
If you will use a tableViewController, the the only difference is that you will add your blockView like this self.tableView.addSubView(blockView)and get the bounds of tableView in the layoutSubviews.

Comment: I got this way to work...although stylistically it is different due to it being a tableViewController. It doesn't block out the entire view, but instead blocks out each row.  I like it better the previous way where the entire view was blocked out. Maybe there's a way to make it also cover up the section headers? Here's what it looks like: https://www.dropbox.com/s/hgxx02257wzi7e1/Screenshot%202016-03-05%2014.01.24.png?dl=0  Also, i had to do blockView.frame = self.view.bounds (.origin caused an error) and blockView.hidden = !dataModel.getAccounts().isEmpty (the reverse).

Comment: Ah..thats; right..I forgot about one thing...In your case it would be better if instead using UITableViewController ..you would use a normal UIViewController with a normal rootView..and inside you would have siblings.. a tableView..and a blockView..now you would create the view hierarchy with adding tableview first to the root view..and then the blockView..this way the blockView will be on top. Off course this controller will have to comply to TV delegate and datasource protocols but that is simple.
In layoutSubviews you would set both views to match the rootView size. Origin was an oversight.